# ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected? Even when the values are numbers?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the table

```
    CREATE TABLE Employee
    (EmpID number(5) primary key,
    SIN Number(9) Not null,
    LastName Varchar2(25) Not null,
    FirstName Varchar2(25),
    Street Varchar2(30),
    City Varchar2(25),
    Province Char(2),
    PostalCode Varchar2(7),
    JobCode Number(4) Not null,
    Foreign Key(JobCode) REFERENCES Job,
    IncomeTax Char(1),
    BirthDate Date,
    HireDate Date,
    JobCodeDate Date)
    TABLESPACE users;
```

This is the line I am trying to insert, there is only three numeric values and all of them are numbers as far as I can see.

```
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(93284,3249028,'fnwei','wefw','213jnijni','32n4','AB','s8j 900',3000,'N','24-Aug-86','07-Jul-03','07-Jul-03');

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

Comment: I believe it is complaining about the dates.  Try using  `to_date('25-AUG-1986', 'DD-MON-YYYY')`

Comment: @KevinBowersox It would depend on his NLS_DATE_FORMAT, right?

Comment: @CJBS Not sure, I'm just playing the hunch that internally the dates are stored as milliseconds past epoch or a number, and passing the string is causing the issue, my sql fiddle seems to work.

Comment: @KevinBowersox If that's the case (and I'm not discounting that it is), then the error is certainly quite obscure.

Comment: @CJBS Have you worked with oracle products? :)  Spend a few minutes in JDeveloper and you will know what I'm talking about!

Comment: @KevinBowersox Very little recently, mostly SQL Server flavours (not that MSSQL errors are always super helpful or informative)!

Comment: Yikes, OPs code works on SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/25770/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alter SESSION set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-Mon-YY';
```

I just had to type this in so that sql will execute the date format in my insert query's correctly

Comment: I was getting ORA-01858 (nonnumeric character was found) for a different SQL; my INSERT INTO didn't contain any dates but one trigger was setting a CREATE_DATE column. I was getting ORA-01858 only on my new Windows10 machine (same SQL worked fine on my MacBookPro and others). Once I typed the above "alter session", I finally got better/proper errors (ORA-02291 integrity constraint violated which lead me to the real issue/bug fix in my case). I'll try to figure out how to set NLS_DATE_FORMAT on DbVisualizer but also on the JDBC driver (I had the misleading error in both places on same machine)

Answer (score 1):

There's possibly a discrepancy between the order of fields as laid out in the INSERT statement, and the order that Oracle is expecting them. I suggest trying again using the full syntax of the INSERT (i.e. specify field names when doing the INSERT). That way, it's absolutely clear the value to field correlation being made.

So something like this:

```
INSERT 
INTO Employee (EmpID, SIN, LastName, FirstName, Street, City, Province, PostalCode, JobCode, IncomeTax, BirthDate, HireDate, JobCodeDate)
VALUES(111, 111,'DEF','ABC','111 111 111.','4535','CC','S6H 1X7',3000,'N','1111-08-24','1211-07-07','1213-07-07');
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is with the date columns try using this syntax `to_date('07-Jul-03','DD-MON-YY')`:

```
INSERT INTO Employee 
VALUES(1111 ,1111,'ABC','DEC','ABC DEC','ABC DEC','BC','BCC 1X7',3000,'N',to_date('01-01-01', 'DD-MON-YY'),to_date('01-JAN-03','DD-MON-YY'),to_date('07-JAN-03','DD-MON-YY'));
```

**SQL-Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0e9df/2

Comment: is there a way that i could specify to sql that all dates here on should be formatted that way instead of specifying it on each insert.